# Solr is turning white space into plus

Tags: solr

I want to make a query like this:

```
q=field:(fu* bar*)
```

for this I am sending this to Solr

```
q=field:(fu*%20bar*)
```

When I look into solr.log I see that Solr executed the following:

```
q=field:(fu*+bar*)
```

Which definitely does not lead to to the expected result. Is this normal and what can I do againt the "space-to-plus-exchange"?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a [default operator](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator) specified in your schema.xml?

Comment: What result do you expect to see and what is the result you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
q=field:(fu*+bar*)
```

In the url encoding, space is +

Comment: Your hint that space is "+" is right. This means, that it is a normal behaviour. (btw: + is %2b.) Your example is wrong. The "+" in "fu*+bar*" does not combine the two expressions "fu*" and "bar*" but is a normal character in the one expression "fu*+bar*".

Comment: "+" character can be used as "space", if you will not percent encode it. If you will then it become a part of your query term.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, heinob. If you want to search for two terms, then use "q=field:fu*+field:bar*".

Comment: I mixed up that "+" is " " and "%2B" is "+". Now everything is fine and your answer lead me to the right path --> green hook!